# Error Accessing Public SOAP Web Service in Salesforce

Tags: force.com-sites, webservices

Is there any way to create a public SOAP web service in Salesforce? I followed the instructions at http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2012/09/creating-public-web-service-in.html , but when I tried to access my web service, I got an error - "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Site under construction"

Comment: Did you make an effort to look in the documentation ?

Comment: I merged Inshar's comment into the question to show that some effort had been expended, and deleted comments that were thereby rendered moot.

Comment: @Inshar Please update your question with more details on what you have set up already, and at what action you get the exception. Without details the very best we can do is make an educated guess.

Comment: Can you post your site URL? Are you including the path prefix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2012/09/creating-public-web-service-in.html

Force Guru had posted a code on how to use sites and create a public webservice .

```
global class DemoClass {
    webService static string Method() {
        return 'DoSomething' ;
    }
}
```

You may need to change the address in your SOAP file
  [image]

Also if you are looking for proper documentation using apex class  methods to expose as WSDLs here is the doc

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_web_services_methods.htm

Comment: Hi Mohith,
Thanks for the reply. I followed the Force Guru link. But, When I tried with the SoapUI to access my webservice I got an error saying "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Site under construction" Any Idea?

Comment: I found the error. Its something wrong with the Endpoint URL. I changed the endpoint url as following. https://**ap1-api.salesforce.com**/services/Soap/class/InsharWS Replace the bolded text with your default web address of your site. In my case, its inshar-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/testWS So finally, It should look like http://inshar-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/testWS/services/Soap/class/InsharWS I only used inshar-developer-edition.ap1.force.com, earlier. That was the issue. Thanks all for your support!

Comment: @inshar, please post your solution as answer (and accept it), or accept on of the given answers so that it becomes clear to other users that your issue was solved :)

Answer (score 7):

And if you want to use REST, I suggest taking a look at:
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html

you basically create apexrest classes, and add the classes to a public salesforce site

Comment: Hi Peiterjan, 
Thanks for the reply. I did the same thing with soap. Also, I changed the binding URL for "http://myDomain-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/services/Soap/class/TestWS" and try to call the webservice with SoapUI. Then I got this error - "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Site under construction" Any Idea?
Thanks

Comment: did you add all the classes to the public site profile access? However i'm not that familiar with public SOAP webservices

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Its something wrong with the Endpoint URL. I changed the endpoint url as following.

https://**ap1-api.salesforce.com**/services/Soap/class/InsharWS

Replace the bolded text with your default web address of your site. In my case, its inshar-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/testWS

So finally, It should look like http://inshar-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/testWS/services/Soap/class/InsharWS

I only used inshar-developer-edition.ap1.force.com, earlier. That was the issue.

Thanks all for your support!

Comment: Next to your (or any other answer in a question you post), you will see a (V) icon which you can click to select the answer as accepted. This will mark your question as resolved.

Comment: @Inshar I just followed all steps, just dont get how to modify the service url, are you downloading the WSDL and uploading it again or how can i achieve it?